# Ajax getJSON PHP JSON getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, json, ajax, mysqli, getjson

I am in the middle of a project, and the getJSON call to a PHP file is working great on my local xampp server to populate a  list.
However, when I run it on my live Godaddy Shared server, i get the error message in the JS Console ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
If I reduce the amount of mysqli records in the php file, it works fine... Is there a setting or limitation that I am not aware of?

I am not a pro by any means, so i figured I would ask for some help here....
My understanding is if it works locally, but not live, then it is a setting on the server, but I have no idea where to start...

I am Sending getJSON call to ajax.php file with various info..
Then the ajax.php file queries mysqli database.
json list created with json_encode which is echoed and returned..
Works great locally with about 900 records, on the server it wont get past 720, if I try to go past 720 I get  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Perhaps the API endpoint has a limit on requests? You're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: I am Sending getJSON call to ajax.php file with various info..
Then the ajax.php file queries mysqli database.
json list created with json_encode which is echoed and returned..
Works great locally with about 900 records, on the server it wont get past 720.

Comment: recieving an empty string means that it wasn't a success...

Comment: This is the second time in as many months I've seen a question regarding response size for GoDaddy servers so it must be something they're doing. I suggest you contact their helpdesk. I'll dig up the other question if it hasn't been deleted

Comment: @sriharichander I understand that. The problem isn't a bad call though, it seems to be some limit on how many records, size, time.... Because if I reduce the amount of records requested, it works fine! Doesn't matter which records either.

Comment: @Phil this sounds more like my issue, any info would be appreciated...

Comment: Found it. The OP even has a solution ~ [ajax GET failing when JSON content over 1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572923/ajax-get-failing-when-json-content-over-1mb). I suspect GoDaddy restricts response content length for specific media types (like `text/html`). Setting the appropriate header for JSON should alleviate the problem

Comment: @Phil YOU BEAUTY!! That did it! I have been on this for the past two days, searching, reading, trial and error! I guess I didn't search or read enough, or I wasn't searching the right thing. Thanks again.

Comment: @Simon make sure you give that question and answer some upvotes so it's easier to find when searching. I've edited it to improve the keywords