# AJAX GET Showing Empty Result On Godaddy With a Bigger Array Size

Tags: php, shared-hosting, jquery-ajax

I have an ajax get script which works perfectly on my localhost irrespective of my array size. Unfortunately when I run the same script on Godaddy host server it returns an EMPTY STRING as the response. If a reduce my php array size to a few rows it works.

I did a little research and applied the fix on this link... [ajax GET failing when JSON content over 1MB on GoDaddy host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572923/ajax-get-failing-when-json-content-over-1mb-on-godaddy-host)
...but I'm still getting the same EMPTY STRING. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code so far...

### PHP

function product_colors_data($con) {

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `colors`");
$data = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

return $data;
```

}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode(product_colors_data($con));

### JQUERY

var row_num = $("#table > tbody > tr").length;

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getcolors.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 30000,
    data: {'row_num':row_num}, // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        //alert(response);
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);                        
    }

});
```

### CONSOLE LOGS

parsererror

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to my problem. It might not be ideal but it gets the job done. I converted 'colors' table to a json file and continued from there. Here is my code...

```
function getArray(){
    return $.getJSON('colors.json');
}

getArray().done(function(json) {
    // now you can use json
    console.log(json);
});
```